# smoother movement?

Tags: xna, timing

I've created a cross silverlight/xna application and I observe that movement is not that smooth.

I'm trying to move a cloud across my screen.

The update interval is once each 33 ms. I've ran the application testing `ElapsedTime.Miliseconds != 33` and that one never hits, so it runs every 33 ms.

What I do each 33 ms is that i take x pos and subtract 5.4 (float) to get the speed I want.

But I observe that the movement aint that smooth, feels laggish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't the best way to handle this problem.
The way you have it now, your cloud movement will run at different speeds based on the computer specifications.  What you should be doing, is moving your clouds based on elapsed time.  This will make your animation behave the same all the time, regardless of how many frames per second you can pump out:

```
xPos -= elapsedTime.Miliseconds * moveSpeed;
```

Set the moveSpeed variable to something that works for you.

Comment: A classic case of `rate * time = distance`. Keep units of measure in mind when you set your move speed. If you are multiplying by milliseconds, then your rate needs to be in distance per millisecond for the multiplication to work out.